# Get the ViewController's name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have an app that is a TabBarControllers with 4 tabs. Now, in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I did this:

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 5.0;
    lpgr.delegate = self;
    [self.window addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
    [lpgr release];
```

This part is working and the long press gesture is recognize in all the four tabs. Now, I want to pass the name of the current ViewController that the user is currently pressing on so I can pass it in my function that handles the long press event.

Answer (score 11):

You can try:

```
NSStringFromClass([YourViewController class]);
```

and for current view controller, use:

```
NSStringFromClass([self class]);
```

Comment: but that will only return the AppDelegate class and not the ViewController class. I want to do everything in the appDelegate instead of putting NSStringFromClass([self class]) in every ViewController.

Comment: @Diffy you can create a public methods (e.g. `selectedViewControllerName:`) for each VC in your tab VC, then you can call the selected VC's method to get the right name of VC. _"I want to do everything in the appDelegate instead of putting NSStringFromClass([self class]) in every ViewController"_, if so, just use the first one, you can return the name by checking the selected VC's `TAG`.

Answer (score 4):

Try Below One(Updated)

AS you Told you have added Four ViewController on TabBar Controller.

Get The ViewController from TabBarController As:

```
UIViewController *current = tabBarController.selectedViewController;

NSArray *controllerNameArray = [current childViewControllers];
```

NSLog(@"className %@",[controllerNameArray objectAtIndex:0]);

I Hope It really Helpful to you...!!!

Comment: thanks but it didn't really gave me what I wanted. I got a clue from your code though,I used UIViewController *current = tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    NSArray *className = [current childViewControllers];
    NSLog(@"className %@",[className objectAtIndex:0]); to get the class name.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an index (0-3) and have a method that will return you the controller from the index (or put the controllers into a public array).